# The response get from curl request in CentOS 7 is different

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, instagram, centos7

I use  **http://instagram.com/username/** this URL for image scraping from Instagram public profiles.
Everything works fine in localhost and works as I expect.

However, in the server(CentOS 7) scenario is different. It does not fetch the same response when I compared it with the localhost (I used "`curl -v http://instagram.com/username/`").

The only difference that I could understand in response headers is **csrf_token** is missing from the server and in localhost, with git bash, it gets attached immediately.

Any hints or answers are appreciated.

PS: I checked in different servers and it gives the same response so it cannot be that Instagram blocked the IP. ^_^

More importantly I use [https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=f92f56d47dc7a55b606908374b43a314&variables={"tag_name":"rose","first":25}](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=f92f56d47dc7a55b606908374b43a314&variables=%7B%22tag_name%22:%22%27%20result.hashtag%20%27%22,%22first%22:25%7D) this URL to scrape hashtag images and it works fine on both server and localhost.

If you can provide something like above is also fine ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, Instagram isn't just going to let you scrape their whole website. They have access-control headers that prevent incorrect embedding and when you do cURL the page will be checking for certain headers, specifically an API key, which you haven't provided and so you are denied.

You need to use the Instagram API : https://www.instagram.com/developer

Comment: i know. its a bit complicated process we have on our application and we cannot use that. scarping is I need.